# CSS line-clamp not working in safari (on Mac)

Tags: html, css

I have 2 problems with the display of line-clamps in Safari browser. First of all the codesnippet:

```css
.clamp-3-lines{
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 3;
  -webkit-box-pack: end;
}

div{
  border: 1px solid black;
  max-width: 30ch;
  p:nth-child(2){
    color: red;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="clamp-3-lines">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quidem nisi unde tempore. Impedit reiciendis est nobis aperiam nulla, pariatur asperiores fugiat id. Quam cum non, eum debitis ab officia quaerat!
  </p>
  <p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quidem nisi unde tempore. Impedit reiciendis est nobis aperiam nulla, pariatur asperiores fugiat id. Quam cum non, eum debitis ab officia quaerat!
  </p>
</div>
```

In Chrome everything is displayed without any problems.
In Safari (on Mac), however, the last line is truncated:
[image]
and in case there are multiple paragraphs, the second paragraph is displayed above the first as if it were absolutely positioned.
I was able to fix the first error by removing the default margin of the paragraph element, but this is not desired.
Unfortunately, since the text comes from a Wordpress backend via a WYSIWYG editor, I can't do anything about the paragraphs either.

Comment: Check this site https://caniuse.com/?search=line-clamp. Line-clamp not supported only safari 3.1 version, Released 2008-2009

Comment: It is certainly a browser after >v15

Comment: I worked around it by removing margin inside textclamping paragraphs and hiding all p:nth-child(1+n)

Comment: Check out my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72170897/17511334) to see if it helps you

Answer (score 1):

In this example you can do the hack

```css
/* add padding for visual consistency */
.clamp-3-lines{
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 3;
  -webkit-box-pack: end;
  padding-top: 1em;
}

div{
  border: 1px solid black;
  max-width: 30ch;
  p:nth-child(2){
    color: red;
  }
}

/* change dislay */
p {
  display: inline; 
}
```

```html
<div class="clamp-3-lines">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quidem nisi unde tempore. Impedit reiciendis est nobis aperiam nulla, pariatur asperiores fugiat id. Quam cum non, eum debitis ab officia quaerat!
  </p>
  <p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quidem nisi unde tempore. Impedit reiciendis est nobis aperiam nulla, pariatur asperiores fugiat id. Quam cum non, eum debitis ab officia quaerat!
  </p>
</div>
```

To learn more about why this happens, click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72170897/17511334)

Comment: Is there anyway to get this done without defining a width  ? I did width 100% but didn't work and I don't want to use some pixels for the width

Comment: @MahdiFaraji you don't have to set the `width`, in this example if there is more than 3 lines of text the text will be cropped