# line clamp (webkit) not working in safari

Tags: css, sass, safari, overflow

```
    display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 5;
  line-clamp: 5;
  -webkit-box-pack: end;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: left;
```

I have this to a P tag but is not working in safari, any other browser works fine

Comment: Remember to include the html and all of the css in your question next time to get better help!

Answer (score 27):

Multi "line clamp" (webkit) not working in safari, if use not `inline` elements.
This example works in chrome (v100) but not in safari (v15.1).

```css
div.hide {
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 3;
  display: -webkit-box;
  overflow: hidden;
}

button {
  margin-top: 16px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container" class="hide">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Officiis ducimus magni, commodi nesciunt tempora unde ipsa repellendus impedit recusandae rem aliquid, alias illum sunt consequatur animi laudantium distinctio odit explicabo.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nobis totam harum laudantium excepturi repellendus similique non est incidunt vero officia saepe error reprehenderit quibusdam, ex tenetur autem impedit soluta culpa.</p>
</div>

<button onclick="document.querySelector('#container').classList.toggle('hide')">Click me!</button>
```

But you can set `display: inline;` for paragraphs, then hiding will work correctly. For indentation you can add a pseudo-element.

```css
div.hide {
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 3;
  display: -webkit-box;
  overflow: hidden;
}

p {
  display: inline;
}

p::after {
  content: " \A\A";
  white-space: pre;
}

button {
  margin-top: 16px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container" class="hide">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Officiis ducimus magni, commodi nesciunt tempora unde ipsa repellendus impedit recusandae rem aliquid, alias illum sunt consequatur animi laudantium distinctio odit explicabo.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nobis totam harum laudantium excepturi repellendus similique non est incidunt vero officia saepe error reprehenderit quibusdam, ex tenetur autem impedit soluta culpa.</p>
</div>

<button onclick="document.querySelector('#container').classList.toggle('hide')">Click me!</button>
```

Unfortunately, this is a hack and may not work in all cases. However, using `display: -webkit-box` and `-webkit-line-clamp: 3` for hiding is also a hack which is missing in the spec, which is probably why safari does not support it.

The most correct and reliable solution is to use js for hiding

Answer (score 3):

One more thing about safari:
this hack

```
.text {
    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-line-clamp: 3;
    overflow: hidden;

    * {
        display: inline;
    }
}
```

won't work in case you need to have `text-align: justify;`.
So just a JS solution can be applied in this case.

Answer (score 1):

line clamp does work on safari.

It doesn't work on inner block level elements:
[CSS line-clamp does not work in Safari on inner block level elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70679732/css-line-clamp-does-not-work-in-safari-on-inner-block-level-elements/70683084#70683084)

```css
.line-clamp{
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  overflow: hidden; 
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<p class="line-clamp">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `<p>` tag often times has browser-defined margins by default, or if you use a CSS library like Bootstrap, so that could be causing your `-webkit-line-clamp` on Safari to seem like it's not working or is buggy.

In my case, I had a `<p>` with a pre-defined `margin-bottom` value inside of a `<div>` that caused the subsequent lines past the `-webkit-line-clamp` limit to be revealed.

On Chrome & Firefox, the following works fine:

```html
<div class="parent">
    <p>Some really long string of text here that eventually gets clamped</p>
</div>
```

```css
.parent {
    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-line-clamp: 1;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

On Safari, since the inner `<p>` had a `margin-bottom`, it affected the height of the parent `<div>` by making the parent taller, and revealing the subsequent lines.

So, my cross-browser solution was:

```css
.parent {
    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-line-clamp: 1;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.parent > p {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the nice explanation. Solved the problem to me.
My problem was that I had put "line-clamp-1" on the <p> tag instead of the wrapper <div> element.

Answer (score -2):

I was experiencing this issue with webkit line clamp not working on Safari for a section with nested rich text elements similar to the code snippet below:

```css
.rich-text-container {
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="rich-text-container">
  <h2>Heading</h2>
  <p>Paragraph content.</p>
  <h4>Another heading</h4>
  <p>More paragraph content</p>
  <ul>
    <li>Unordered list item</li>
  </ul>
  <ol>
    <li>Ordered list item</li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

To get the line clamping in Safari to behave similarly to Chrome, the most straightforward workaround I found  is to toggle a `maxHeight` value using JavaScript.  The value should be set to the same or a slightly higher height than is actually required so that it doesn't interfere with the behavior in Chrome and cut off any of the bottom of the last line.

In my case, multiplying the number of lines to clamp by `3.25` and using `em` for units seems to work well enough (ex: for `-webkit-line-clamp: 2` using `maxHeight: 6.5em`).

The limitation of this workaround is that you do not get the ellipsis behavior at the end of the last line in Safari as you would in Chrome.

Here is an example code snippet with the workaround:

```js
var isClamping = false;

function toggleClamping() {
  isClamping = !isClamping;
  document.getElementById('toggleButton').innerText = isClamping ? 'Show more' : 'Show less';
  document.getElementById('textDiv').style.webkitLineClamp = isClamping ? '2' : '';
  document.getElementById('textDiv').style.maxHeight = isClamping ? '6.5em' : '';
}
```

```css
.rich-text-container {
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="textDiv" class="rich-text-container">
  <h2>Heading</h2>
  <p>Paragraph content.</p>
  <h4>Another heading</h4>
  <p>More paragraph content</p>
  <ul>
    <li>Unordered list item</li>
  </ul>
  <ol>
    <li>Ordered list item</li>
  </ol>
</div>
<button id="toggleButton" type="button" onclick="toggleClamping()">
    Show less
</button>
```

***Note:*** the webkit line clamping behavior in Safari only seems to have issues when the line clamping is set on a parent element with nested elements. Setting line clamping on individual html elements works fine in Safari as shown in the example below:

```css
.rich-text-element {
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<p class="rich-text-element">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc ac commodo nulla. Suspendisse eu vehicula libero. Donec rutrum velit in turpis blandit condimentum. Nullam ullamcorper varius elit non venenatis. In faucibus metus in rhoncus mollis. Mauris
  blandit tincidunt urna nec sodales. Nunc et justo sagittis, bibendum risus euismod, vehicula odio. Nam a fermentum ex, et luctus erat. Aenean ac arcu lobortis, imperdiet arcu in, maximus leo. Quisque dictum dignissim magna, efficitur tincidunt ligula
  ornare non. Quisque mi mauris, pellentesque pharetra mi ac, rutrum luctus diam. Sed gravida nunc ac mauris sodales vestibulum.
  <p/>
```

Comment: This does not work.

Comment: @AlexTitarenko thanks for pointing out that the original answer didn't work.  It was only working for a very specific use-case. I've updated the answer to a more generic workaround.